# "В частности" — выделяется ли запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Выделяется ли запятыми оборот "в частности" в середине предложения в таких случаях: "Он играл на многих инструментах(,) в частности(,) на гитаре"?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таких случаях обособляется весь присоединительный оборот, в который они входят: *Он играл на многих инструментах**,** в частности на гитаре.*

Comment: Ага, то есть, после "в частности" запятая не ставится. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Верно, не ставится. После *то есть,* кстати, тоже не ставится. :) Не за что, всегда рад помочь.