# Нужно ли обособлять "в частности"?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Нужно ли обособлять "в частности" в следующем предложении:

**В письме Фонда(,) в частности(,) сказано...**

Answer (score 2):

В письме Фонда, **в частности**, сказано.

"В частности" является вводным словом и обособляется, о чем сказано в словаре "Трудные случаи русской пунктуации".

Пример: В ней, **в частности**, сказано: «Астрономия является одной из старейших фундаментальных наук…  [Ефрем Левитан. Международный год астрономии // «Наука и жизнь», 2009]

Нет обособления в конструкциях вида "вообще... и в частности", когда "в частности" является наречием.

Answer (score 1):

**В Вашем предложении** "в частности" - **вводное слово,** которое необходимо выделить запятыми:

***В письме Фонда, в частности, сказано...***

Некоторые особенности, правила, примеры и ссылки Вы можете посмотреть *на нашем же сайте:*
[**В частности - ставить ли запятую?**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/37477/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E)
[**"В частности"**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1320/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)
[**Пунктуация - “в частности”**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/23067/%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)